# Angular 2 : View changes but route does not on clicking back button

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using : `"@angular/router": "3.0.0"`

Issue is that when I press the back button of the browser, the view changes to the previously loaded view however, the route does not change.

What is the issue here ?

When I change the route in my application I use :  **this.router.navigate(['/abc']);**

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit and found that the changelog of the angular router has fixed these issues.

I have upgraded to router 3.2.3 and it works fine on Google Chrome/Ubuntu